# Just trying to concatenate output from `aws s3 cp ...` with a date but date being gobbled

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface, cp

I have a bash script which logs what it does with `aws s3`, prefixing each log message with a date. When I try to prefix the output of the `cp` command, the date doesn't appear. The same thing works with `rm`...

This works

```
echo "$(date) $(aws s3 rm ${S3_BUCKET}${i})"
```

This only outputs the aws output

```
echo "$(date) $(aws s3 cp ${DUMP_FILE} ${S3_BUCKET})"
```

So I get something like this...

```
Sun Dec 16 09:30:21 GMT 2018 purging all but the latest 4 agent backups
Sun Dec 16 09:30:21 GMT 2018 rm <file>
Sun Dec 16 09:30:21 GMT 2018 delete: s3://<folder> (this is AWS output with my date prefix)
Sun Dec 16 09:30:22 GMT 2018 take backup
Sun Dec 16 09:30:22 GMT 2018 backup complete
upload: ./<file> to s3://<bucket> (where's the date prefix!)
```

I've tried it directly in the shell too with the same result

Comment: Do both commands print to standard output, not standard error? What output precisely do you get from your current attempt?

Comment: I get the output of the AWS call, but the date doesn't appear. That's the actual output above - see the last line not showing a date at the start.

Comment: It's still not clear if the output is printed to standard output or standard error. The latter would trivially explain why your code doesn't capture it.